# File upload with tdo-miniforms not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the TDO-miniforms plugin for wordpress.  I have a form set up that lets the user submit files. The files are successfully uploaded to the tmp-folder, but once the post is created they are not copied into the allocated post folder. The only thing that is created in the folder with a post id is a file called array. It seems like the file holds the binary data of the uploaded files.

The “correct” urls are appended to the post content

I am running wordpress 2.9.2 on snow leopard using Mamp.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the developer of the plugin. Usually they are more likly to help. The name Array indicates that the developer has forgotten to pick the correct value from an array.

Comment: Unfortunally the developer has stopped support 8 days ago - bad timing indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with uploads and I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin and then it worked. As it happens, I did my new install at the exact right moment because the newest version was just published on Wordpress.org today just as I did the "Add New" plugin from within my WordPress installation. It grabbed the new version that was added today: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/

Of course, uninstalling the previous version would be nastier if you already have user submissions. I did not.